# select count() in a view

Tags: mysql, count, sql-view

Well, if I try to count the total of rows of a view like

```
select count(*) from my_view v
```

It always returns `1` knowing that the view has a lot of rows. I do not find any documentation about it in mysql docs. If it is not possible, is there a workaround to achieve this task? thank you.

**Edit**, the view has not primary key, then I also tried something like this with the same result of `1`:

```
select count(v.id_customer) from my_view v
```

Here is an example:

```
mysql> select * from plans limit 5;
+----------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
| medical_center | customer | invoice | product | recurrence | placed              | due_date            | elapsed_months | elapsed_days |
+----------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
|              1 |        1 |       1 |       2 |          6 | 2015-01-18 17:16:23 | 2015-07-18 17:16:23 |              2 |           89 |
|              1 |        1 |       3 |       2 |          6 | 2015-04-18 17:16:23 | 2015-10-18 17:16:23 |              5 |            0 |
|              1 |        1 |       4 |       2 |          6 | 2015-04-18 17:16:23 | 2015-10-18 17:16:23 |              5 |            0 |
|              1 |        1 |       5 |       2 |          6 | 2015-04-18 17:16:23 | 2015-10-18 17:16:23 |              5 |            0 |
|              2 |        1 |       6 |       2 |          6 | 2015-04-18 17:16:23 | 2015-10-18 17:16:23 |              5 |            0 |
+----------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, trying to counting:

```
mysql> select count(*) from plans p;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       1 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Are you using any application level code to perform the above query or you are trying directly on mysql ?

Comment: directly from a mysql console. Always return `1`

Comment: Would you mind sharing the result into the question just copy paste entire result into the question that you are getting in mysql cli.

Comment: This is weird, I have never seen this , I just tried creating a view from a table and then `count` it works well.

Comment: this drive me crazy, but at least it is possible to call  `count()`. I am very tired after some spent hours in this situation. Tomorrow I will update here.

Comment: Not sure if it has to do anything with cache however you have try something as `select sql_no_cache count(*) from ...` just to confirm its not cache issue.

Answer (score 4):

If your view calculates the count, eg

```
create view my_view as
select count(*) as count from my_table
```

then just:

```
select * from my_view
```

The view returns only one row (the count rssult), so if you select the count of the view rows, of course it will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * , (select count(*) FROM my_view) AS Cnt FROM my_view
```

`count(*)` is an aggregate function that would need a group by clause to work. But the above is a workaround to help you now.

Answer (score 0):

instead try like this

```
select count(table_id) as countno from my_view
```

you will get the correct value count

Comment: How it is different than the OP ? why you think it will give correct result ?

Comment: he just wants to count the total no of rows of the my_view table right...? by this he can achieive that

Comment: So how your query is different than what he has `select count(*) from my_view v` it should do the same is't it.

Comment: Actually I tried this variant too (passing the name of a column), but I get the same result